# How to use my voice instead of default voice in text-to-speech Android?

Tags: text-to-speech

I want to use my voice instead of default voice for the text-to-speech in Android. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can not replace the voice in default TTS, but you can use external engine and add your voice there.

For example, you can use [Flite](http://www.festvox.org/flite/) TTS with your own voice. To add your voice, record voice samples from the existing database (500 samples) and build your voice with the build scripts, then add your voice into TTS. That will take some time though.

Comment: "*You can not replace the voice in default TTS, but you can use external engine and add your voice there.*" Doesn't work. No matter which engine I choose, the phone will use the default, on-board voice.